# Can't choose price in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

it seems bug on iTunes connect. i couldn't set price in all my apps in new itunes connect. can't click "choose" , "other currency" and "plan a price change" doesn't do anything.

[image]

I couldn't submit to store (even though it's an app update). iTunes force me to update the price

[image]

does anyone experience the same ?

---

**UPDATE**

It's working fine now. it seems it was just for short period time. hopefully no recurring in future.

Comment: I had actually set my price last night, then logged in this morning to submit the application (was waiting for the dreaded 'processing' status before I could select the latest version number).  Once I submitted the latest version, it complained that the price was NOT set.  I must say that the Android process nowadays seems much more developer friendly, I don't experience long delays after downloading whilst processing and the approval process to the store is typically 2-3 hours.

Comment: (FYI - I've tried Chrome and Edge, same problem, so it's not localised to Safari)

Comment: @Bigood While I understand that it may fit more there, most people don't even know that site exists and will check here. As it's not a programming but still developer concern, I'd like this question to be answered here. I understand that "formally" it doesn't suit here but still let the page be for people instead of being so formal...

Comment: So glad I found this SO question! Now I know I am not alone and can stop trying to open it in different browsers, disable blockers, debug the browser's javascript and DOM and other sillinesses.  Why the app submit and review process needs to be so frustrating every single time ?!?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug-report in a 3rd party piece of software, not a question.

Comment: _"unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming"_ , I don't think there is any other usage for iTunes Connect besides being a tool for programmers...

Comment: It's working for me now (simply refreshed the page). The price tier is back to what it was and submitting the app for review succeeded.

Comment: It's happening again in 2021... For a few days now I can't select any prices. The dropdown appears empty.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any solution to this ?

Comment: @endavid It's working now